# REST API doesn't seem to work

Tags: 8

Login with CURL:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--request POST \
--data '{"name":"admin", "pass":"admin"}'
http://d8.local/drupal-8.5.6/user/login?_format=json
```

Then the result:

```
{"current_user":{"uid":"1","roles":["authenticated","administrator"],"name":"admin"},"csrf_token":"LUa3_xAXC8CgDkCoDoKonAmJ8hYFF6gZTak_LpaHFco","logout_token":"90jJUh08H437-F5fU25eq7rS2b8FS22eVVy_Fcsk2TA"}
```

Look good. But when I tried to check login status:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "X-CSRF-Token: LUa3_xAXC8CgDkCoDoKonAmJ8hYFF6gZTak_LpaHFco" \
--request GET \
http://d8.local/drupal-8.5.6/user/login_status?_format=json
```

The results is: 0. So it failed.

Same result when I did with Vue resource.

Note: Postman seems to work, but it's working like real browser without CSRF token need.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

REST API doesn't work with CURL because you don't send cookie after login. By default, Drupal 8 using [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/basic_auth/overview) after the login user has a cookie. Browser (include postman) will store this cookie and send to the server any request. So It works normally.

If you want REST API working with CURL. You need to store cookie when request login, and send this cookie to check status login like this:

```
curl -c ~/cookie.txt
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--request POST \
--data '{"name":"admin", "pass":"admin"}'\
https://dfs3w.ply.st/user/login?_format=json
```

in line

```
-c ~/cookie.txt
```

mean that write cookie to file **cookie.txt**.

After login successfully, I will read cookie and send cookie to check status login:

```
curl -b ~/cookie.txt
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "X-CSRF-Token: -LSxwKsxEnupbeM4NANfV1JLtlGeqK0dRPxhRRSFvkU"\
--request GET \
https://dfs3w.ply.st/user/login_status?_format=json
```

Comment: Thank you for info. So with cookie set, it's working now and look like CSRF Token is not need.

Comment: Yes, the routing **[/user/login_status](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/user/user.routing.yml?h=8.5.x#n150)** does not need CSRF Token. Every routing has requirement **_csrf_token**, you need to set  X-CSRF-Token to header. 
ps: Xin chào Việt Nam :D.

Comment: Great to know. I'm from DA NANG :)

Comment: My skype is doidinhdoi, feel free contact me. :D